# Visual Neo4J DB on Cytoscape Plugin

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cytoscape

Good afternoon,

We are working on a tool, that would be needed to use Neo4J, a graph database. Also there are a lot of plugins which we can visualize the nodes, think we are going for Cytoscape.js.

The Neo4J database was created but at the moment we are trying to import/load the database using ajax calls, to visualize the nodes / graph.

Anyone who have experience with this? Or worked on any similar projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you google "neo4j cytoscape" you'll immediately find:

http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/cyneo4j

Is this not what you'd be looking for?

Comment: this is a Java application, we are looking for a driver/plugin on how to connect to Neo4J db, query and get nodes to visualize on cytoscape for example. Thanks :)